# Incrementing CX counter in Assembly (TASM)

Tags: loops, assembly, increment, tasm

I have this assembly code that I've been working on for the past few days. Its for a homework of mine that has the conditions that should print out Characters from 'A' to 'J' but with an asterisk between each letter
Output: A*B*C*....J*.

The limitations of what we should add is that we can only use one data container `dl`. Plus we can only use looping and jump conditions.

I've mostly finished my work but I've been having a problem figuring out why my counter `cx` isn't incrementing well within my code. Here's my code:

```
.model
.code
org 100h
s: mov ax, 3   ;
   int 10h     ; just clearing the screen
   mov ah, 2
   mov cx, 1   ; counter is just set to one for possible increment
   mov dl, 'A' ; A is added to data container
   int 21h     ; prints out A
x: mov dl, '*' ; first asterisk is then added to container, replacing A
   int 21h     ; asterisk is printed out A*
   mov dl, 'A' ; asterisk is replace by A in the counter
y: inc dl      ;
   loop y      ; loops at y then increments container dl, A + 1-> B
   int 21h     ; prints out container, A*B
   inc cx      ; where the problem lies. Should increment but not
   cmp dl, 'J' ; if the character in container is not above j, jumps to..
   jna x       ; ..where x is
   int 20h     ; ends but doesnt due to infinite looping, container not reaching 'J'
end s
```

If the increment works, what I think would happen is that every time the process jumps to x and then passes to loop y, given that `cx` has been incremented, it will loop and increment the container depending on how much the counter `cx` holds after multiple increments. This will lead to the container reaching the condition of getting above the letter J.

So that's pretty much my problem. Thank you in advance for any help I could get.

Comment: Maybe using add instead of inc. add cx, 1 or w.e the add instruction is.

Comment: I don't get the task description, what means that "limitation" to `dl`? You are using `cx` for data too. And any way, if you are doing per-char stream output, you will have to destroy `dl` by `'*'` value, and restore it then back to letter, so you definitely must use something else for data. So what exactly is the limitation? No memory buffer? No stack usage? `dh` can't be used? Why `cx` can?  BTW, can you write directly into VRAM without `int 21h`? :D Then it would be trivial :D (actually not, would need more registers for write ptr :/ )

Comment: Ohhh, sorry about that, I guess the limitation that I should have said is that I can't store the value of dl to another container. It should be destroyed by adding '*' and then restoring it in my own way through loops or jump conditions.

Comment: "You can't store `dl`" is the only limit? Then you can simply count `'A'` to `'J'` in `cl`. And copy `cl` into `dl` ahead of letter output, then overwrite the `dl` with `'*'`. What I'm trying to say, that I'm not against exercises with artificial limits, but this one so far doesn't make much sense to me.

Answer (score 3):

It is incrementing just fine, as you could see by using a debugger. The issue is that you have a `loop` command which will decrement `CX` until it is zero. Therefore incrementing will always make `CX` to be 1.

Push `CX` to stack before `loop` and pop it out after if you want to keep the value. And grab a debugger to debug the code yourself.

Or since you just want to increment `DL` by `CX`, why not just say `ADD DL, CL` and not use loops?

Comment: Thank you. :D i'll try implementing 'add' instead.